# gettext command-line utility not looking up translations

Tags: locale, translation, gettext

I'm trying to translate some strings using `gettext` from a shell script under Linux, but have had no success. For example the following always returns the untranslated string:

```sh
LC_MESSAGES=et_EE gettext iso_639-3 'Estonian, Standard'
```

I've tried setting many combinations of `LC_ALL`, `LANG`, `LANGUAGE` and `LC_MESSAGES` environment variables to `et`, `et_EE`, `et_EE.UTF-8` or empty strings, but nothing seems to work, even when using a clear enviroment (e.g. with `env -i LC_MESSAGES=et_EE`).

Although `gettext --help` clearly shows that the standard search directory is `/usr/share/locale`, the respective translation files (e.g. `iso_639-3.mo`) are properly installed in under `/usr/share/locale/et/LC_MESSAGES/` and `locale-gen` has properly been run, `gettext` does not seem to look for the translations from under `/usr/share/locale/`. Output from `strace -f -e trace=%file` has shown that `gettext` only tries to read `/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive`, `/usr/lib/locale/et_EE/LC_MESSAGES` and `/usr/lib/locale/et/LC_MESSAGES`, with the last two `openat()` system calls failing with `ENOENT` as those files don't exist.

I'm probably just doing something plain stupid and don't know how to use the `gettext` utility. What am I doing wrong? How to properly use the `gettext` tool?